# Kano survey - Why Expect/Expect is not questionable

Tags: kano-model

I don't understand why the couple answer expect/expect from kano survey is "indifferent" but not "questionable.
Does not it mean the question has been misunderstood ?

Below a reminder for kano survey

[image: kano survey]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the way the Kano model works, if a user does not display a strong and valid opinion about the presence or absence of a feature than it is conservatively marked as indifferent. Whereas if a user says that they dislike the absence and the presence of a feature then you have to question whether they understood or answered the question correctly.

The reason for the pairing is to provide a couple of checks against the user's response to the question. The first is to gauge the relative magnitude of the response by comparing the presence and absence questions, and the second is to check whether the responses provided by the user is consistent (e.g. they might have been given an incentive to complete the survey and therefore rushed through it).

The questionable category reflects those questions pairs that did not pass the check against consistency of the response.

Comment: @user3460047 just out of interest, what are you using the Kano model for? I have posted questions previously about the use of the model, and it doesn't appear to be as popular as I might have expected.

Comment: @MichaelLai The Kano model is great, but it's a little like running focus groups -- the answers you get out of context aren't always reliable. Making them more reliable takes hard work and a deep understanding of human psychology and the Kano system. End result: a lot of people don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you read earlier documentation about Kano, it labels expect/expect and tolerate/tolerate as questionable, not indifferent.

I've found this document to be very helpful in understanding edge cases like this. It also talks about how to grade results when you have even distribution across the different sentiments.

http://walden-family.com/public/cqm-journal/2-4-Whole-Issue.pdf